# How do I make the background image scroll in an overflow: auto box?

Tags: css, background, overflow

I want the background to scroll with overflow: auto.

Is this possible with pure CSS?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is customize your background image for the div.  You can control scrolling behavior with the [background-attachment](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-attachment.asp) directive.

Comment: I don't think that works with something scrolling with overflow. It's the first thing I tried but the bg scrolls as normal.